# Finding the inverse of x^(e/x)

Tags: functions, inverse-function

While messing around on my graphing calculator, I stumbled upon this function:

$$f(x)=x^{\frac{e}{x}}$$

I was unable to find the inverse of this function using online calculators. What is the inverse of this function, and how do I go about finding it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f^{-1}(y) = - \dfrac{e W(-\ln(y)/e)}{\ln(y)}$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Do you know of any online services or tools that I can use to see what such a graph would look like?

Comment: @Anonymous To draw any inverse function plot the original function then swap the $x$ and $y$ axes. I.e. reflect the curve in the line $y=x$.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+y%3Dx%5E(e%2Fx)) does a good job of calculating and plotting the inverse.

Comment: @IanMiller On desmos.com, it ends up looking like this: http://imgur.com/iG7JxD9 - Is this the correct result then?

Comment: Yes. That agrees with the graphic in the [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+y%3Dx%5E(e%2Fx)) link.

Comment: @IanMiller Thanks!